# Query help – distinct records with max

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have a table called `activities` with person, sport and the date the person played the sport. Example:

```
person | sport      | date
--------------------------------
jane   | soccer     | 09/15/2012
sam    | basketball | 09/10/2012
jane   | tennis     | 09/12/2012
sam    | basketball | 09/08/2012
sam    | soccer     | 09/04/2012
jane   | tennis     | 09/01/2012
sam    | basketball | 08/27/2012
jane   | football   | 08/23/2012
```

I need the rows containing the newest date a person played a sport. The results would be:

```
person | sport      | date
--------------------------------
jane   | soccer     | 09/15/2012
sam    | basketball | 09/10/2012
jane   | tennis     | 09/12/2012
sam    | soccer     | 09/04/2012 
jane   | football   | 08/23/2012
```

You can see here that, for example, the row for Jane playing tennis on 9/1 is excluded because she also played on a newer date of 9/12.

What would this query be? I'd prefer non sub-query answers, but all answers are welcome. Also, both MySQL and PostgreSQL answers are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
      select person, sport, max( date) as date 
      from activities
      group by person, sport
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this possible without a sub-query?

Comment: Is this possible with PostgreSQL? I tried and got an error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7287f/6

Comment: copy paste exact sentence. All non aggregate columns must be listed on select clause one by one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` in PostgreSQL (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/04d79/4)):

```
select *
from 
(
  select person, sport, date,
    row_number() 
      over(partition by person, sport order by date desc) rn
  from yourtable
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi bluefeet, reading OP comments I have change my mind, your select is more close to solution. +1